# Error using "08" and "09"

Tags: bash

I have a problem with numbers 08 and 09. When I get the number of the day of the month (01..04...09...), and I use it inside an if, I receive an error with numbers 08 and 09. How can I solve this error?

The error is 
    [[: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
I don't get any error with the other numbers.

```
datelaptop=`date +"%d"`
echo $datelaptop
if [[ $datagfs -eq $datelaptop ]] ; then
#if [[ 09 -eq 09 ]] ; then
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `08` and `09` have a leading zero and are being interpreted as octal numbers. `08` and `09` are invalid octal numbers hence this error.

You can use base 10 arithmetic in `((...))` to compare 2 values:

```
if (( 10#$datagfs == 10#$datelaptop )); then
...
fi
```

`10#$datagfs` will interpret `08` to `8`